# javascript (in Firefox addon) stop page load

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, redirect, settimeout

First off: **Everything works**, but I would like to fine tune this a little.

Basically, in my FireFox addon I have this code in function A:

```
timervar = setTimeout(function() { quick.redirectToAnotherUrl(); },1500);
```

and in the redirecttoanotherurl function I have this:

```
window.content.location.href = FilterUrl;
```

The problem is the page loads before the redirect takes effect.
Is there anyway to stop the page loading totally and then redirect as normal?

Comment: Why isn't the page nothing more than the message that the user is being redirected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the browser compatibility, but maybe try `window.stop();` before your `setTimeout`?

For IE, you may need `document.execCommand('Stop');` in addition, because as far as I know, it does not support `window.stop()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 1.5s delay specified in your argument to `setTimeout`.

In fact, if you want an immediate redirect, I don't understand why you're using `setTimeout` at all.

Just set `window.content.location.href` immediately.

Comment: No, I need to have a delay because I am showing a notification for 1.5secs to the user that they are being redirected (I don't want the user to think some scummy virus or bad addon has hijacked his browser) but in that 1.5 secs I want to stop loading the page.

Comment: @Ryan: I don't think that you can control that.